# Whats wrong with my python program

Tags: python

## tip and tax calculator

```
bill = price + tax + tip

price = raw_input("What is the price of the meal")

tax = price * .06

tip = price * 0.20
```

what is wrong with my code
I have tried everything 
please answer and get back to me

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a `string`.

Comment: what is your expected output and your actual output? Or is there an error? What is the error in that case?

Comment: What error are you getting? One obvious error is that price, tax and tip are all used before declared. You're probably getting that error at least.

Answer (score 2):

a few things.

```
bill = price + tax + tip  #You can't add up these values BEFORE calculating them

price = raw_input("What is the price of the meal") #raw_input returns a string, not a float which you will need for processing

tax = price * .06 #So here you need to do float(price) * .06

tip = price * 0.20 #And float(price) here as well.

#Then your " bill = price + tax + tip " step goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't use variables that you haven't defined: in your code your are using `bill = price + tax + tip` but your program doesn't even know what price, tax and tip are yet, so that line should be at the end of the code, after you've asked the price and calculated tax and tip.

Then, you have `raw_input`, this function returns a string, if you want to convert it to a decimal number that you can multiply and add (float) you can use `price = float(raw_input("what is the price of the meal"))`

Correct that two things and it should work...

Answer (score 1):

Heres a couple of things wrong with the code:

1. You're trying to calculate the total before some variables have been defined.
2. The `raw_input` function returns a string so you can't do proper mathematical calculations before you coerce it into an integer.
3. In calculate the tips/tax you should use a float with the whole number 1(`1.20`) to take the whole value of the bill + 20%.

Below is a code snippet that should work how you want and give you something to think about on how to pass dynamic values into the modifiers within the `calculate_bill` function for custom tip floats and custom tax floats:

```
def calculate_bill(bill, bill_modifiers):
    for modifier in bill_modifiers:
        bill = modifier(bill)
    return bill


def calculate_tip(bill, percentage=1.20):
    return bill * percentage


def calculate_tax(bill, percentage=1.06):
    return bill * percentage


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bill = int(input("What is the price of the meal: "))
    total_bill = calculate_bill(bill, [calculate_tip, calculate_tax])
    print(total_bill)
```